# Choosing 3 biggest numbers from many variables and use the values to echo appropriate reaction

Tags: php

I am trying to pull the 3 biggest numbers from a set of variables. The variables are pulled from a database and are different for every class of students.

I want to distinguish 3 topics that require improvement for each class of students. Here is an example that shows how I do it. The problem is, as long as this is partially working (can distinguish 3 highest values), it fails my expectations when one of the $reg variables is the same as another one. How can I include this option?

```
$highest1=0;
for ($i=1; $i<=7; $i++) {
  if ($highest1<=${"reg$i"}) {
$highest1 = ${"reg$i"};
  }
}

$highest2=0;
for ($i=1; $i<=7; $i++) {
  if ($highest2<=${"reg$i"} && ${"reg$i"}!=$highest1) {
$highest2 = ${"reg$i"};
  }
}

$highest3=0;
for ($i=1; $i<=7; $i++) {
  if ($highest3<=${"reg$i"} && ${"reg$i"}!=$highest1 && ${"reg$i"}!=$highest2) {
$highest3 = ${"reg$i"};
  }
}

#if any $reg.. are the same this chain will stop at the first met requirement for if. So if there are two areas with the same number only one will be shown!

  if ($highest1 == $reg1) {
    $area1= "Fractions, %, decim";
  } elseif ($highest1 == $reg2) {
    $area1= "Factors";
  } elseif ($highest1 == $reg3) {
    $area1= "Simplifying";
  } elseif ($highest1 == $reg4) {
    $area1= "Fractions of numbers";
  } elseif ($highest1 == $reg5) {
    $area1= "Share in ratio";
  } elseif ($highest1 == $reg6) {
    $area1= "Reverse Ratio";
  }  elseif ($highest1 == $reg7) {
    $area1= "Compound interest";
  }  elseif ($highest1 == $reg8) {
    $area1= "Problem Solving";
  } else {
    $area1= "Something went wrong";
  }

  if ($highest2 == $reg1) {
    $area2= "Fractions, %, decim";
  } elseif ($highest2 == $reg2) {
    $area2= "Factors";
  } elseif ($highest2 == $reg3) {
    $area2= "Simplifying";
  } elseif ($highest2 == $reg4) {
    $area2= "Fractions of numbers";
  } elseif ($highest2 == $reg5) {
    $area2= "Share in ratio";
  } elseif ($highest2 == $reg6) {
    $area2= "Reverse Ratio";
  }  elseif ($highest2 == $reg7) {
    $area2= "Compound interest";
  }  elseif ($highest2 == $reg8) {
    $area2= "Problem Solving";
  } else {
    $area2= "Something went wrong";
  }

  if ($highest3 == $reg1) {
    $area3= "Fractions, %, decim";
  } elseif ($highest3 == $reg2) {
    $area3= "Factors";
  } elseif ($highest3 == $reg3) {
    $area3= "Simplifying";
  } elseif ($highest3 == $reg4) {
    $area3= "Fractions of numbers";
  } elseif ($highest3 == $reg5) {
    $area3= "Share in ratio";
  } elseif ($highest3 == $reg6) {
    $area3= "Reverse Ratio";
  }  elseif ($highest3 == $reg7) {
    $area3= "Compound interest";
  }  elseif ($highest3 == $reg8) {
    $area3= "Problem Solving";
  } else {
    $area3= "Something went wrong";
  }

Echo "<h3>The areas for development for this class are as follows:</h3><h2>".$area1."<br>".$area2."<br>".$area3."</h2>";
```

Comment: More data needed. What are you starting with? What are you getting that is wrong/write? If this all comes from a data base. Any reason you cant to this in sql?

Comment: You could shorten the code (that we can see) by converting the values `"Fractions, %, decim"` into an array and use values like `$highest1` as an index into this array.

Comment: Why do you use several variables when they could all be in an array making the code super simple

Comment: For the first part, make an array of $reg1, $reg2,..., $reg7. Then use sort() function on that array. The first three elements of new array will be what you have currently as $highest1, $highest2,  $highest3. For the second part, make an array that has keys $reg1 to $reg8 and values your strings. Then, simple lookup on that array would remove the need to do if/else. If still not clear, I will post an answer at some point tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Are the values integers?  If so simply assign them to an array, sort it and pick the last three values from it.

You might want to give example of what these values are and what you want to happen when #3 matches #4 (display both? display the first one?)

Comment: The values $reg... are percentages that my students collectively per each topic in the assessment - so they vary from 0-100. I want to highlight the highest 3 scores and display the message for each one of these scores. What I have got at the moment is the 3 highest scores in this long multiple 'if' statement but if there are two results that are the same let's say $reg1 == $reg2, then $reg2 will be skipped and I want it to be included in the 3 highest scores. So I want to display both #3 & #4.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply...but just in case.   There are many ways to do what you want but the way I would do it is as follows:

```
<?php
# assuming the scores are a string - however you get the values we just need them in an array
$scores = "97,37,55,82,99,97,55,97,73,100,62,91";

# explode the string into an array
$scores_array = explode(",", $scores);
# this makes:
    //  Array
    // (
    //     [0] => 97
    //     [1] => 37
    //     [2] => 55
    //     [3] => 82
    //     [4] => 99
    //     [5] => 97
    //     [6] => 55
    //     [7] => 97
    //     [8] => 73
    //     [9] => 100
    //     [10] => 62
    //     [11] => 91
    // )
# now put them in a new array - so that we can sort and count them
$sorted_array = array();
foreach ($scores_array as $key => $value) {
    # a ternary for counting how many of each score we have
    $sorted_array[$value] = (isset($sorted_array[$value]) ? $sorted_array[$value] + 1 : 1);
    # this makes:
        //  Array
        // (
        //     [37] => 1
        //     [55] => 2
        //     [62] => 1
        //     [73] => 1
        //     [82] => 1
        //     [91] => 1
        //     [97] => 3
        //     [99] => 1
        //     [100] => 1
        // )
}

# sort the array by key (score)
ksort($sorted_array);

# get the top 3 in the array
$top_three_array = array_slice($sorted_array, -3, 3, true);

# output them
foreach ($top_three_array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br />";
}
# prints:
    // 97: 3
    // 99: 1
    // 100: 1
```

?>